# Delphi XE6 "Error reading form"

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

Been having an issue since the last few XE releases, after opening a project, if the first form I open in the IDE has a considerable amount of VCL, I get an error like this

[image]

This also happens if the project had been saved with that form opened last time I closed it, then the error pops right as I restart Delphi and it automatically loads the last project or after loading the project.

It happens only after the first time I open Delphi. If I close the project and then reopen it without closing the IDE, this doesn't happen.

It's not specific to TPngImageList, the component varies from project to project. When this happens I must be careful not to save the form, otherwise the references to those items are lost, I must close without saving then open it again, and then the error is gone.

[image]

Any idea what's wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: It generally means that the design-time package that the offending component is defined in isn't loaded in the IDE at the time you load the project. Check your Component | Install Packages... dialog in the IDE.

Comment: Packages all seem to be fine. If I open a smaller form that contains the component that fails it works.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to fix it:

https://www.idefixpack.de/blog/ide-tools/ide-fix-pack/

> "Disable IDE Package and Palette Cache"