# Delphi XE3: Error reading form. Class not found

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I'm working on a code which is developed by another person exactly on the same PC that I'm using now. When I open the project I get the following error:

[image]

If I select Ignore or Ignore All, I'll screwed up and nothing will work properly, but of I select Cancel, I'll get the following message:

[image]

The class which is mentioned here is available in a file with different name. 
I have seen this problem in different websites and also here, but not of the solutions worked for me.  Any suggestion?

Comment: Installing a package, or otherwise configuring a library in the IDE, is specific to the user account on Windows. When you created a new account, you are now using a fresh IDE. However, you did not provide that information in your question, it was later exposed in the comments of David's answer.

Answer (score 3):

The message indicates that the design time package containing the named class has not been installed into your IDE. This is a devexpress component, and it may just be that you have not installed devexpress on this machine.

Comment: This PC has not had a problem for running the code before. I have made a new account for myself, do not have access to the other account, I now I have this problem. I think it should be something with the settings,  but I can't find it.
In this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25405185/delphi-xe6-error-reading-form I saw a proposed solution: 
[  http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ide-fix-pack/

"Disable IDE Package and Palette Cache" ]

I tried if but it didn't work.

Comment: Install the missing design time package. Probably going to be easiest to reinstall devexpress. When you moved to a new user account you lost all the settings.

Comment: I reinstalled the whole package, but still it has the same problem. I can't find any setting to add this class to the code. Any idea?!

Comment: This problem is also addressed here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Installing_Component_Packages
and the solution here is in another way. I tried to add the line mentioned here, but it didn't work. I think it should related to a setting which I can't find it. Do you have any idea?!

Comment: I stand by my answer

Comment: Late comment. David is correct. Check the list of installed packages. (Component->Install Packages) Make sure there are check boxes ticked fro the Developer Express Inc components that aren't working. If they don't exist in the Design Packages list, you'll need to to Add them